# Document / Folder (Parent Child) Display - only show folders with contents

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm

I am building my own simple document display model with the concept of Directories (Folders) with containing Documents.  I have built the database and can successfully get a list of all the documents that are in each folder.  My security model has only security on a document level and NOT on a folder level so when i render out the display of folders (and documents) alot of the time many users are seeing empty folders which are not relevant.  What is an efficient way of filtering out the folders that don't contain direct children of documents (except those that have nested folders who DO contain documents)

Below is my recursive function that generates my JSON

```
        public List<DirectoryViewModel> FlatToHierarchy(List<Data.Directory> list, List<MyDocumentsViewModel> documents, Guid? parentId = null)
    {
        return (from i in list
                where i.ParentId == parentId
                select new DirectoryViewModel
                {
                    Id = i.Id,
                    Description = i.Description,
                    ParentId = i.ParentId,
                    Name = i.Name,

                    Documents = documents.Where(x => x.DirectoryId == i.Id).ToList(),
                    Directories = FlatToHierarchy(list, documents, i.Id)
                }).ToList();
    }
```

and below is an example of the output generated

```html
{  
   "Directories":[  
      {  
         "Id":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
         "Name":"Front of House",
         "Description":"Checklists \u0026 Evaluations",
         "ParentId":null,
         "Documents":[  
            {  
               "LatestVersion":false,
               "Id":"7a580b85-edff-4c18-9ba4-ea893a5b1c11",
               "Name":"Welcome Pack",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603479817)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"263.822 KB",
               "Url":"",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603479817)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":false,
               "Id":"b288a86d-370e-43b2-a938-f817468ccc44",
               "Name":"scenarios",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603539867)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"816.909 KB",
               "Url":"",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603539867)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":false,
               "Id":"67ac3117-309b-40d5-82ca-424de9723d20",
               "Name":"Tour",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603617990)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"262.362 KB",
               "Url":"",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603617990)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":false,
               "Id":"734bf12e-a219-4190-b390-0369901174bb",
               "Name":"Evaluation Sheet",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603797893)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"670.168 KB",
               "Url":"",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603797893)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":true,
               "Id":"64907293-4fde-4f5c-a6f3-640e002c8122",
               "Name":"Walk-through",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603503013)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"500.525 KB",
               "Url":"https://xxxxx5VtqKA",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603503013)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":true,
               "Id":"bcdb12a6-de80-45c3-ac97-0cab879a4b34",
               "Name":"staff",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603575103)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"279.536 KB",
               "Url":"https://xxxxxaVnDfQ",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603575103)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":true,
               "Id":"b1d02b16-a0ba-4100-ada0-ce36ec647f36",
               "Name":"Checklist",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603522967)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"244.976 KB",
               "Url":"https://xxxxxdSngtA",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603522967)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            },
            {  
               "LatestVersion":true,
               "Id":"226ceb41-ff93-4a4a-963b-3afbefe75a57",
               "Name":"Cheat Sheet",
               "Description":"",
               "Extension":"pdf",
               "Secured":false,
               "Printable":true,
               "Downloadable":true,
               "CoverImage":"",
               "Public":false,
               "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509603555770)\/",
               "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
               "Version":1,
               "DirectoryId":"8072d20b-c424-465e-87be-7b09ad64a6cc",
               "Size":"788.114 KB",
               "Url":"https://xxxxxjyqoBQ",
               "VersionNotes":"",
               "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509603555770)\/",
               "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
            }
         ],
         "Directories":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "Id":"e9d28c6b-8e6d-4429-8ea4-eb3dc3bc64eb",
         "Name":"Franchise",
         "Description":"All things xxx",
         "ParentId":null,
         "Documents":[  

         ],
         "Directories":[  
            {  
               "Id":"d0c9eced-9d02-4332-be47-f1ff2e5a7fe6",
               "Name":"Fitout",
               "Description":"Description",
               "ParentId":"e9d28c6b-8e6d-4429-8ea4-eb3dc3bc64eb",
               "Documents":[  
                  {  
                     "LatestVersion":true,
                     "Id":"b0c17fbe-fd15-4343-9032-039e79d461bc",
                     "Name":"Finding and Fitting out Your xxxx (Deck)",
                     "Description":"",
                     "Extension":"pdf",
                     "Secured":true,
                     "Printable":false,
                     "Downloadable":false,
                     "CoverImage":"",
                     "Public":false,
                     "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1509524413437)\/",
                     "CreatedBy":"Christopher",
                     "Version":1,
                     "DirectoryId":"d0c9eced-9d02-4332-be47-f1ff2e5a7fe6",
                     "Size":"8.395 MB",
                     "Url":"https://xxxxxPhIf5g",
                     "VersionNotes":"",
                     "ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1509524413437)\/",
                     "ModifiedBy":"Christopher"
                  }
               ],
               "Directories":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction (either a JS or C# based approach (would prefer backend though) that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
        from i in
            (from i in list where i.ParentId == parentId select i)
        let subDirectories = FlatToHierarchy(list, documents, i.Id)
        where (documents.Any(x => x.DirectoryId == i.Id) || subDirectories.Any())
        select new
        {
            ...
            Directories = subDirectories
        };
```

Comment: Is this done in the recursive statement or is this done afterwards?  I need to make sure it can cope with a nested folder 3-4 deep with one document in it without destroying its parent folders (which don't have a document directly in it)

Comment: Have edited to include checking for sub-directories.

Comment: When i implement this i get  a Stack Overflow exception..looks like it is endlessly recursive?

Comment: Although...at first glance i can't see how its "that" much different :/

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think I can see the problem...you only want to do the `let subDirectories = FlatToHierarchy(list, documents, i.Id)` for records where i.ParentId == parentId.

Comment: sorry if this sounds stupid..but how'd you actually do that :)  Im not that used to the let syntax.  - -Thank you so far for your assistance btw!

Comment: Edited. Personally I wouldn't use that syntax. You could just do  `from i in list.Where(li => li.ParentId == parentId)
            let subDirectories = ...`